# Automatically open external links with iframe?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I am working on a WordPress site that has a lot of authors.  The stories often contain external links, and I am looking for a way that we can automatically have external links open with a small header that has a "Back to our site" link, along with a close button.

Ideally this would be done automatically, but we'd also like to be able to create links manually that open in this same sort of iframe with our header.  How can I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build this via Javascript, so you could easily turn it off/on as needed and it will be kind of portable too and you can use it on other site as well.

steps to do:
Go through all the anchor links and if the href is external link, add attribute target blank, and change the href links

```
 if(external_link){
   a.target = '_blank';
   a.href="http://example-ownsite.com/iframe_holder/?page="  + a.href;
 }
```

Then take a look at my page on http://fedmich.com/works/odesk/ 
so you could provide a vertical scrollbar on the iframed page.
Im using a function called resizeIframe() there

Note: some sites dont want to be placed inside iframe and they will breakaway from the topframe.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like it will do the trick for links on our site.  Would it be possible to do without Javascript?  So we could use it on links sent via email, or other services that don't allow for use of Javascript?

Comment: Yes, it can be done via PHP code as well.
When you said its going to be used as email, then server processed is the way to go. Let me make you a function you can use.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It will probably be used in a few different situations -- Some in email, some from articles on the website itself.

Comment: Would there be a way to create a standard link format, that you could just plug any URL into and have it display with our header on top?  For example `http://domain.com/external-banner.php?url="http://google.com`?

Comment: Yes, I'll make a variable for you, that you can change later on. Hold on, Im coding it up now :)

Comment: Try this code, put it in your functions.php
https://github.com/fedmich/StackOverflow-answers/tree/master/11199286

Comment: After adding the code to my functions.php, the sample output is returned on my website itself -- Both in the Dashboard and on the frontend.  Also, what do I replace the `http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/` link with?

Comment: Also -- If I use the Javascript in your original answer -- How do I make it dynamic?  For example, how would I output the `href` of `<a href="http://external-site.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Hide Frame and go to Link</a>`

Comment: Sorry to bombard you with responses, but also, if I add `<script type="text/javascript">
if(external_link){
   a.target = '_blank';
   a.href="http://my-website.com/my-header.html?iframe-name="  + a.href;
 }
</script>` to my `<head>`, this doesn't add the iframe. It just opens the links in a new window (as `_blank` does).

Comment: Hi Ryan, 

You can use is_admin to determine if you should apply the filter
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

You can use a php page to output that link/top frame